# Change the name of gmon.out file when compiling with -pg

Tags: gcc, profiling, gprof

Is it possible to change the default name of the file gmon.out, which is created when the profile flag (-pg) is set when compiling with gcc, to, for example, [executable name].gmon.out?

I need this because I have more than one executables, which are located in the same directory, and have to run parallel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not so short, but actually the answer is YES - if using `glibc` (at least with version 2.11.1, which is the version I used to test this).

To have your `-pg` compiled and linked executable create different names then the default `gmon.out`, just set the environment variable `GMON_OUT_PREFIX` to a value of your choice and the profiling output will be written to `[value of your choice].[pid]` where `[pid]` is the process-ID of the process the profiling data belongs to.

Comment: A little late, but thank you very much for the answer. I'll keep that in mind. :)

Comment: You should really accept this answer, the other is simply false.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. The profiling file created by running your program once it has been compiled with the -pg command is ALWAYS called gmon.out. However, once produced you can safely rename it to something else (for example foo.bar) and analyse it later using the command:

```
gprof test.exe foo.bar > analysis.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Since this is not possible, I am now profiling with cachegrind and valgrind. This worked out for me.